# AngularJS refresh attributes in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an object consisted of couple of attributes and the object is set to the scope. Those attributes are bound with page elements. Moreover, that object is passed into a filter. My problem is when I set a new object to the scope, the filter still has the previous attribute values of previous object. If those attributes are set separately, then the filter has the updated values.

`$scope.student = {name:'Alex', year: 4, cls : 'high'} ;` // if this student object is set later in the application,
`$scope.student = {name:'John', year: 8, cls : 'primary'} ;`  // filter still has the previous values (student.name is 'Alex')

But,  attributes are changed separately, 
`$scope.student.name = 'John';` // filter has the latest values.

Is there a way to refresh internal attributes values in a object bound to scope ? (Angularjs 1.3 is used.)

Modified: Usage in page

```
Registration::
<span class="std-infobar"> Info: {{student.name}} |{{student.year}}  </span>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML where this variable is used?

Comment: @ignacykasperowicz . Thanks for your attention. I updated my answer.. However, those elements on the page is updated. Big problem is, filter doesn't get the updated values. :(

Comment: @charlietfl . Thank you.. problem exists in the filter. Filter doesn't get the updated values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is defined like

```
$scope.student = {name:'Alex', year: 4, cls : 'high'};
```

and later you do

```
$scope.student = {name:'John', year: 8, cls : 'primary'};
```

you reassign object breaking reference. It means that new `$scope.student` object has no connection to the previous one. Your filter will not update, because Angular relies heavily on such object references.

Now you can understand why `$scope.student.name = 'John'` works: `$scope.student` doesn't change, it's property does. This is not Angular specific behavior but normal Javascript thing.

Here is a rule then: if you want to change an object like you want make sure you change a property, not reassign entire object. So you could do:

```
$scope.student = {profile: {name:'Alex', year: 4, cls : 'high'}};
```

and later you can set new student as

```
$scope.student.profile = {name:'John', year: 8, cls : 'primary'};
```

In this case make sure to use `student.profile` object in filter.

Comment: Thank you very much to show my problem. When the structure of object and the way it bound to the scope were changed, IT WORKED !!!

Comment: Great, glad it was useful.